# Android Studio -> Test Passed: 0 passed

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-testing

I request a little help with this problem. I'm doing this tutorial to refresh memory and update my knowledge with new state of the art "Developing Android Apps with Kotlin".

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012

On class 6, lesson 10, there is this source code: https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker/tree/Step.03-Solution-Create-RoomDatabase

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun insertAndGetNight() {
    val night = SleepNight()
    sleepDao.insert(night)
    val tonight = sleepDao.getTonight()
    assertEquals(tonight?.sleepQuality, -1)
}
```

Supposedly, it should pass a test, but after executing it, it returns this:

```
Test Passed: 0 passed.
```

And in the terminal of the right I can read this:

Running tests

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -m    -e debug false -e class 'com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.SleepDatabaseTest#insertAndGetNight' com.example.android.trackmysleepquality.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
"Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle" option was ignored because this module type is not supported yet.
```

What is wrong with the project and why the test is not passed?

I added a text manually writing it, and the result is the same, 0 test passed. This is the test I added:

```
@Test
fun addition_isCorrect() {
    assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
}
```

Also, I tried unchecking the box next to Run Android instrumented tests using Gradle in the testing settings (Go to File>>Settings>>Testing) with same result.

Comment: Please any solution?

Comment: @Fayçal read the accepted answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I downloaded the source code and figured out that **testInstrumentationRunner ** is missing so you need to add it in gradle.build

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.trackmysleepquality"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

and room operations need to be inside a coroutine scope so without it compiler is giving error

```
    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun insertAndGetNight() {
        runBlocking {
            val night = SleepNight()
            sleepDao.insert(night)
            val tonight = sleepDao.getTonight()
            assertEquals(tonight?.sleepQuality, -1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you soooo much, it worked. How is possible that they forgot that in the lesson? maybe that has changed recently? One more question. In the testing documentation, https://developer.android.com/studio/test/test-in-android-studio google sais that if you press "Control+Shift+T" in a function, a pop up must appear for generating a test. Is not working. Instead, it displays this message: "No test subjects found". Any idea about how to generate a test from a function?

Comment: Nope I didn't try before

Comment: my case is placing the wrong package name of the runner, thanks for answering!!